# Reading emails by batch using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the following code which I wanted to retrieve by batch (for example: fetch first 50 messages, process it and then fetch next 50). Currently it fetches all the messages and store it in an array.Does Javamail supports that? If not how to retrieve by batch?

Thanks for answers.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(host, userName, password);

Folder inbox = null;
inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(
        new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
inbox.fetch(messages, fp);
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
{
    //Process a message
}
```

UPDATE:

I have tried to implement batching as follows but it is not working as expected.

The issues are:

- Suppose there are 24 email in inbox then `totalUnread` is showing correct but `Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN),
              false), inbox.getMessages(batchStart, batchEnd));` is returning only 5 instead of 10 records as the `BATCH_SIZE` IS 10.
- Another issue is the emails which are processed are not marked as read eventhough `getContent()` is called.

  ```
  private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
  AuthenticationService authenticationService = null;
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
  Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
  store.connect(host, userName, password);
  Folder inbox = null;
  inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
  int totalUnread = inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
  if (totalUnread != 0)
  {
      inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
      int batchStart = 1;
      int batchEnd = (totalUnread > BATCH_SIZE ? BATCH_SIZE
              : totalUnread);
      int batchCount = 0;
      while (true)
      {
          processABatch(inbox, batchStart, batchEnd, batchCount);
          batchStart = batchEnd + 1;
          if (batchStart > totalUnread)
          {
              break;
          }
          batchEnd = ((batchEnd + BATCH_SIZE) < totalUnread ? (batchEnd + BATCH_SIZE)
                  : totalUnread);
          batchCount++;
      }

  }
  inbox.close(true);
  store.close();
  }

  private void processABatch(Folder inbox, int batchStart, int batchEnd, int batchCount)
          throws MessagingException
  {
      Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN),
              false), inbox.getMessages(batchStart, batchEnd));
      FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
      fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
      fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
      inbox.fetch(messages, fp);
      for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
      {
          processMessage(messages[i], inbox);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `inbox.search(new FlagTerm(...))`, you might want to do `inbox.search(new FlagTerm(...), getMessages(start, end))`. It uses the [`getMessages(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#getMessages%28int,%20int%29) method which allows you to retrieve a subset of all messages in the current `Folder`.

Indeed `getMessages(start, end)` applies to the complete `Folder`. According to the Javadoc of that method, `Message` objects are expected to provide light-weight since they are only a reference to the actual message.

So maybe you could write a method that returns the first `50` unread messages, by continuously fetching messages and putting them in a `List` or something like that, until you either have 50 messages in it or you've reached the end of the `Folder`. The result of that message would be the "batch".

Afterwards, you could do the usual processing of the messages.

Comment: It looks like the suggested approach will not work in this case as `getMessages(start, end)` is applied to the complete inbox instead of the current filter which is to retrieve only unread emails. Any other possibility other than read all (read and unread) emails and batch it?

Comment: I've updated the original answer based on your additional question.